# Symfony2 Production incorrect "404"

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, production-environment

I'm trying to change my environnement from dev to prod.
When i'm trying to go on an invalid route with prod env, i get the dev error page " NotFoundHttpException:" , instead of the prod error page like "e-mail us..." .

There is my app.php :

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
/*
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Try: AppKernel('prod', false);  and clear the cache.  Not sure if it will help or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `app.php` file includes `new AppKernel('prod', true)`. The second argument of the constructor determines whether it's in debug mode or not. The first argument only determines the name, which can be used when loading environment-specific config files.

As long as debug is enabled, the error pages show the verbose version with lots of information helping you to *debug* your application. In production, you never want debug to be enabled and you want to set it to `false` (this is also the default in the Standard Edition):

```
// ...
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
// ...
```